# Sharepoint Validation Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to write a validation formula with the sytax below. but it is throwing an error in SharePoint.

```
= 
IF( 
AND([QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]="N/A",[QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="N/A",[QC Complaint Risk Level]="N/A",[QC Non Complaint Reason]="N/A",[Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]="N/A",[Trigger Phrase Word(s)]="",[Trigger Phrase Score]=""),
"New", 
IF( 
AND( 
[QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]="Yes",OR([QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="N/A",[QC Complaint Risk Level]="N/A",[Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]="N/A")
),"Error", 
IF( 
AND([QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="Yes",OR([QC Non Complaint Reason]<>"N/A",[QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]<>"Yes",[Trigger Phrase Word(s)]<>"",[Trigger Phrase Score] <> "", [Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]="N/A", [QC Complaint Risk Level]="N/A"))
,"Error", 
IF( 
AND(LEFT([QC Valid Call (Yes/No)],2)="No",OR([QC Complaint (Yes/No)]<>"N/A",[QC Non Complaint Reason]<>"N/A",[Trigger Phrase Word(s)]<>"", [QC Complaint Risk Level]<>"N/A", [Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]<>"N/A"))
,"Error", 
,"Valid" 
))))
```

Please help!

Comment: What can `[QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]` be other than `Yes` or `No`?

Answer (score 1):

It's easier help you when you add more details about situation, such as why this validation statement, or what else you've tried. Without knowing your business requirement, I can't help you make shorter validations.

But syntactically, your validation is correct with the exception of an additional comma in your last `IF` statement. Here's the revised formula:

```
=IF(  
   AND(
      [QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]="N/A",
      [QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="N/A",
      [QC Complaint Risk Level]="N/A",
      [QC Non Complaint Reason]="N/A",
      [Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]="N/A",
      [Trigger Phrase Word(s)]="",
      [Trigger Phrase Score]=""
   ), 
   "New",  
   IF(  
      AND(  
         [QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]="Yes",
         OR(
            [QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="N/A",
            [QC Complaint Risk Level]="N/A",
            [Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]="N/A"
         ) 
      ),
      "Error",  
      IF(  
         AND(
            [QC Complaint (Yes/No)]="Yes",
            OR(
               [QC Non Complaint Reason]<>"N/A",
               [QC Valid Call (Yes/No)]<>"Yes",
               [Trigger Phrase Word(s)]<>"",
               [Trigger Phrase Score] <> "", 
               [Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]="N/A", 
               [QC Complaint Risk Level]="N/A"
            )
         ),
         "Error",  
         IF(  
            AND(
               LEFT([QC Valid Call (Yes/No)],2)="No",
               OR(
                  [QC Complaint (Yes/No)]<>"N/A",
                  [QC Non Complaint Reason]<>"N/A",
                  [Trigger Phrase Word(s)]<>"", 
                  [QC Complaint Risk Level]<>"N/A", 
                  [Wells Fargo Related (Yes/No)]<>"N/A"
               )
            ),
            "Error", 
            "Valid"
         )
      )
   )
)
```

I have a feeling like this could be greatly reduced in length if you talked about your conditions more. But as for now, this should work.

Comment: Hey... I deleted the comma at the end .. I tried to edit the statement before it got to you.

Comment: With that being said.. it still did't go through.

Comment: @TravisHorne Can you please explain your logic in your question? We may be able to come up with something easier. Till then I'll take a look at the formula a bit more.

Comment: It's a pretty lenghty logic.... I'll try to type it out